# Closed-form solution to an infinite series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form, geometric-series

I have the following series that I've confirmed on matlab to have *some* closed-form solution, but I can't find it through trial-and-error, and I definitely don't have the math background to just solve it. Here it is:
$$ \sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^t(1-\delta)^t $$
Where $\beta,\delta\in(0,1)$. Any help would save me oodles of time that I need to spend doing the rest of the problem set (that isn't math problems; this is ancillary to the subject).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), and
$$ 
\sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^t(1-\delta)^t 
=\sum_{t=0}^\infty (\beta(1-\delta))^t
=\frac{1}{1-\beta(1-\delta)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This sum converge becouse it is
$$=\sum_{i=0}^\infty [\beta(1-\delta)] ^t$$
With argument $\beta(1-\delta) <1$.

If converges to
$$\frac{1}{1-\beta(1-\delta)}$$

Comment: Oh god, of course. Thank you!